# AngularJS if statement condition in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I'm using `ng-repeat` in AngularJS

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="question in questions" class="question list-group-item media">
        <span class="question__type">{{ question.question }}</span>
        <br>
        <div class="btn-group question__answer justified nav-tabs">
            <a class="btn {{question.type}}" ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">{{ answer }}</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to make the section below into an if statement where `if {{question.type}} == 'radio' then justified` on the `btn-group` div.

```
        <div class="btn-group question__answer justified nav-tabs">
            <a class="btn {{question.type}}" ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">{{ answer }}</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-class`.  Here is a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/suqereho/1/edit) demonstrating that it works.  I've made the `justified` class change the text color to red.

```
<div class="btn-group question__answer nav-tabs" ng-class="{justified: question.type == 'radio'}">
    <a class="btn {{question.type}}" ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">{{ answer }}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class directive :

```
<div class="btn-group question__answer justified nav-tabs" 
   ng-class="{question.type =='radio' ? 'radio-class : 'other-class'}">
            <a class="btn {{question.type}}" ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">{{ answer }}</a>
        </div>
```